# Matlab ODE - Simulink integrator with sum block in m-file without simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, ode, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Is it possible to do something like this

```
     ----        -------
 --->|+ |------->| 1/s |-----o--------->
     | -|        |     |     |
     ----        -------     |
       /|\                   |
         --------------------
```

in a matlab ode m-file without the usage of simulink?
And if it is possible how is it done? Maybe someone has 
got a code snippet of something that works this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes it's possible, but nobody's going to do it for you. The steps would be:

1. Write down on paper the differential equation of the system
2. Put it in a form `dy/dt = f(t,y)` and write it as a MATLAB function
3. Solve the differential equation with one of the MATLAB `ode` solvers, e.g. [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) (there are plenty of examples on the documentation page)

**EDIT**

As I said it doesn't get much easier than this...

[image]

Comment: Ok. I know that but it seems I wasn't able to express. I know how to write the differential equation and also how to solve it with matlab. what I don't know is how to produce that feedback shown up there during the integration! I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: That's basic maths. See http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorSpeed&section=SimulinkModeling for example.

Comment: The example you showed me are using simulink. I don't want to use simulink. I just want to use matlab and call the solver directly with a function I wrote. The only thing I need is that behaviour shown up there in my funtion ... that is the question. I'm sorry but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: The example I gave you does use Simulink, but more to the point shows the relationship between the mathematical equations and the block diagram (including the feedback loop). Use it to derive the equations of your block diagram, it's really not that hard.